# Computing probabilities for sums of random variables

Tags: probability

Let $p$ be some probability and let $X_i$ be random variables such that $X_i = x_i$ with probability $p$ and $X_i = 0$ otherwise, where $x_i$ are fixed positive constants, for $i=1,...,n$.

If I fix some probability $\pi$, how do I efficiently compute $c$ in the following equation?

$$P\left(\sum X_i < c\right)\geq\pi$$

Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify: What is being summed with $\sum$; are $X_i$ taken in order of their subscripts or in random order? Pretty clearly $\pi \ne 3.14159\dots.$ Knowing the context, application, or purpose of this would be helpful. Showing what you have tried might also help.

Comment: Thanks for responding. $\pi$ is just some constant probability. What is being summed is the sum of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables, the usual $X:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to set $c=1+\sum x_i$, then 
$$
P\left(\sum X_i<c\right)=1 \geq \pi
$$
for all possible probability value given to $\pi$.